# Perform method on each string separated by whitespace or hyphen

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am given a string and it can contain letters, whitespaces, and hyphens. Example:

```
str1 = "abcdef ghi-jkl"
```

I want to perform a method `method` on each *word* in `str1` (*word* here is a sequence of letters. It is delimited by a whitespace and/or hyphen).

For example, on `str1`: `method("abcdef")`, `method("ghi")`, `method("jkl")` will return `"abcdef* ghi*-jkl*"` (`*` is the outcome of each string method). `method ("abcdef ghi-jkl")` is not equal to (`method("abcdef")` `method("ghi")` `method("jkl")`). Whitespaces and hyphens will be returned to where they were originally.

How can I perform this?

My hunch is to use method combined with some sort of regex method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def the_method(s)
  "[#{s}]"    # just an example
end

str1 = "abcdef ghi-jkl"
str1.gsub(/[^ -]+/) { |match| the_method(match) }
# or a bit shorter:
str1.gsub(/[^ -]+/, &method(:the_method))
# or a bit faster:
block = method(:the_method)
str1.gsub(/[^ -]+/, &block)

# all of those produce:
# => "[abcdef] [ghi]-[jkl]"
```

Comment: This is very cool, I didn't know you could supply a block to `gsub`. BTW, using a lambda, the notation would be even simpler: `the_lambda = ->(s) { "[#{s}]" }; str1.gsub(/[^ -]+/, &the_lambda)`

Comment: @KeithBennett: I assumed `the_method` already exists as a method as described by OP. If it doesn't, it makes no sense to use a lambda when you can directly use the block.

Comment: True.  I guess I should have worded that as a general suggestion to the ether. ;)